# Using reactive extensions to hold onto the most recent event in a series of events until x seconds after most recent event has been received

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I am trying to understand how the following scenario could be implemented using reactive extensions.  Other solutions that I have been looking at involve managing a series of timers... something that I am looking to avoid if possible.

**Scenario**
A stream of "ActionRequests" occurring.  The ActionRequest's streaming in are from different object sources.   I am only interested in picking off the most recent ActionRequest once requests have stopped coming in from a specific source for a period of x seconds

So breaking that down.

Events are being continuously received from different object sources.

The different object sources are denoted by a guid - see the ActionRequests class

After x number of seconds of silence from the object source the latest event is pushed out.

The older messages can be discarded once a more recent ActionRequest of interest has been received

```
public class ActionRequest
{
    public ActionRequest(Guid quoteId, DateTime now)
    {
        QuoteId = quoteId;
        RequestTimestamp = now;
    }

    public Guid QuoteId { get; set; }
    public DateTime RequestTimestamp { get; set; }

}
```

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually have to buffer the events for some reason, or do you just want to respond to the latest event after x seconds of "silence", thus skipping the earlier events?

Comment: That is a good question.  It would not really be necessary to buffer all of the events, just as long as the most recent event for each QuoteId was pushed out after a period of silence.  I will update

Comment: Then Observable.Throttle should do it, like Dave said in the Rx Forums.  No?

Comment: Throttle sounds like it should do the trick.  I am looking to discriminate on the QuoteId guid.  I have replied to Dave's post in a little more detail on the Rx Forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was provided in [RX Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/06c3bad0-f019-4487-af6d-d8aaa4da8b61) by Richard Hein.

Short version of the answer is below.  A more complete sample has been added to the thread in the RX forums.

```
var throttled = observable.GroupBy(tar => tar.Value.QuoteId).SelectMany(g => g.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500)));
```